# How to compute Contrast improvement index (CII)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, contrast

Hi im wondering how to compute CII. From what i know to obtain it:

[image]

Where: 
[image]

For **a** is the mean gray level of the **foreground** and **b** is the mean gray level of the **background**. 
Im confused at the part how to separate foreground and background of the image.

Anyone have any solution / enlightenment for me?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Contrast is usually calculated from minimum and maximum brightness values. Not from foreground or background.

Modulation (or Michelson Contrast) is defined as

M = (L_max - L_min) / (L_max + L_min)

If you want to calculate that from foreground and background you'll have to distinguish between both. This is referred to as image segmentation.

You'll find plenty of resources for that keyword and there are countless ways to achieve that.

Comment: This is what got me confused, a one resource in matlab forum say to calculate CII the same way with your answer, some even add sliding window to it. But from many papers define CII as the equation written above where it use foreground-background mean gray level. It will affecting the metrics (CII) when using segmentation as there are exist many different techniques which will provide different (segmentation) results.